# Add a Div element with a <p> inside and <section>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to web developing, I need help about how to insert a div with a `<p>` tag inside a section using javascript or jquery?

Thank you!

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<section class="section-countdown">

<!-- i want to insert a <div> <p> </p> </div> here.-->

    <h2>THIS CONGRESS BEGINS IN</h2>
    <ul class="countdown">
        <li> <span id="days"></span>
            <p class="days_ref">DAYS</p>
        </li>
        <li class="seperator">:</li>
        <li> <span id="hours"></span>
            <p class="hours_ref">HOURS</p>
        </li>
        <li class="seperator">:</li>
        <li> <span id="minutes"></span>
            <p class="minutes_ref">MINUTES</p>
        </li>
        <li class="seperator">:</li>
        <li> <span id="seconds"></span>
            <p class="seconds_ref">SECONDS</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append elements into the DOM with JS you can use the `element.appendChild(childNode)` method.

This method requires you to first create a childNode that will be appended later.
You can do that by using `document.createElement(typeOfElem)`.

If you plan on appending many elements at once consider using `document.createDocumentFragment()` first, so that you don't redraw the DOM every time you append an element but instead you append it at the end, after every child node has been added.

In your example you need to specify the parent by selecting it with a `document.querySelector('.section-countdown')` and assigning it to a const variable, for example `const sectionCountdownSelector` (if you are not planning on using babel use `var` instead).

Example code below:

```
const sectionCountdownSelector = document.querySelector('.section-countdown'); // select your div

const docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); // to not redraw DOM every time
const divElement = document.createElement('div'); // create a div elem
divElement.setAttribute('class', 'your-desired-class'); // assign a class to it

const paragraphElement = document.createElemet('p'); // create a p elem
paragraphElement.setAttribute('class', 'your-another-class'); // assing a class to it
paragraphElement.innerHTML = 'inner text in the paragraph'; // add text to p elem

docFragment.appendChild(divElement); // append div elem to your fragment
divElement.appendChild(paragraphElement); // append p elem to div elem

sectionCountdownSelector.appendChild(docFragment); // this appends the elem on your DOM
```

Using `document.createDocumentFragment()` is recommended if you do a lot of `appendChild()` one after the other. If you need to append single element then just use `appendChild()` the usual way.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("section.section-countdown").prepend("<div><p>text</p></div>");
```

Comment: thank you for this! i have found a another solution, I've just make a empty div with no class and I just use the $("").addClass();

Comment: i will try this also if my another solution doesn't work